# Within a Pipeline, is it possible to access a Google Cloud Storage bucket in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Within a pipeline, is it possible to do TextIO from/to a cloud storage file in another cloud project?

Accessing a BigQuery table in another project seems possible with "my-project:output.output_table" and setting up service accounts properly.

However, with TextIO, I have not been able to find a way to specify the project ID in conjunction with my file pattern "gs://some/inputData.txt".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.  You will want to make sure that the appropriate access is present (compute engine account, cloudservices account, detailed below).

To change bucket permissions, you can use gsutil.  You will want to add these accounts:

- [project-number]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
- Google Compute Engine service account

You can use this command:

```
gsutil acl ch -r -u <email address of service account>:FC gs://<BUCKET>
```

To check bucket permissions:

```
gsutil getacl  gs://<your bucket>
```

Note that Cloud Storage buckets exist in a global namespace: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-naming#requirements

**Permission Details**:

When you run Cloud Dataflow locally (using a DirectPipelineRunner) your pipeline runs as the Google Cloud account that you configured with the gcloud executable (using gcloud auth login). Hence, locally-run Cloud Dataflow SDK operations have access to the files and resources that your Google Cloud account has access to.

When a Cloud Dataflow pipeline runs in the cloud (using a DataflowPipelineRunner or BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner), it runs as a cloudservices account ([project-number]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com). This account is automatically created when a Cloud Dataflow project is created, and it defaults to having read/write access to the project's resources. The cloudservices account performs “metadata” operations: those that don’t run on your local client or on Google Compute Engine workers, such as determining input sizes, accessing Cloud Storage files, and starting Compute Engine workers. For example, if your project is the owner of a Cloud Storage bucket (has read/write access to the bucket), then the cloudservices account associated with your project also has owner (read/write) access to the bucket.

Google Compute Engine (GCE) instances (or workers) perform the work of executing Dataflow SDK operations in the cloud. These workers use your project’s Google Compute Engine service account to access your pipeline’s files and other resources. A GCE service account (-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) is automatically created when you enable the Google Compute Engine API for your project (from the Google Developers Console APIs and auth page for your project).

Comment: Thx. I understand the permissions, GCS ACLs, service account emails etc. I just don't see how to specify another project ID in the TextIO object that differs from the PipelineOptions object. In this filepattern "gs://some/inputData.txt", the "some" bucket needs to be in the same project as the Pipeline. afaict.

Comment: Is your question about the Cloud Storage namespace?  It's global, so gs://some isn't scoped by project ID.

Comment: fantastic. that is the piece of information I was missing. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-naming#requirements. thanks for your help.